# why is string IndexOf() acting case-INsensitive?

Tags: c#, string, linq, linq-to-sql, indexof

I'm really stumped by this one.  I'm learning LINQ and used Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition to connect to a SQL Server database containing information about my books.  I created the LINQ to SQL classes as needed.  That stuff obviously works.  It all works except I cannot figure out for the life of me why, if I search for "SR" (uppercase), it finds two records, "SR-71 Revealed, The Inside Story", as expected, but it also finds "Faded Sun: Kesrith" where the "sr" is lowercase.  I'm using the IndexOf() method of the string class, which is supposed to perform a case-SENSITIVE comparison, right?  The output displays the second book title as shown above, with the "sr" in lowercase.  Here's the pertinent part of the code:

```
// normal using directives here
namespace QueryBooksDB {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            var urgh = new BooksDataContext();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a string to search for:");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();

            var list = from book in urgh.Books
                        where book.Title.IndexOf(str) > -1
                        orderby book.Title
                        select new { ID = book.BookId, book.Title, book.Location };

            foreach ( var b in list ) {
                Console.WriteLine(b.Title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SQL Server is not case sensitive by default.

Answer (score 10):

At the final step your query is translated into sql. In SQL server string alike fields (varchar, nvarchar) are case insensetive. So
`select * from tbl where col like '%foo%'` will retrieve if the value is `Foo` or `FOo`

Comment: Ahh, LINQ to SQL, you so crazy.

Comment: Ok...thanks!  So to make sure, I guess I have to re-check the returned titles with IndexOf AGAIN to make sure the case is correct before I output them.

Comment: @user1013210 or you change the `collation` for your database to a case-sensitive type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I thought it was case-sensitive by default, but you can always use the `StringComparison` overload to specify case sensitivity:

```
test.IndexOf("foo", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

`StringComparison` enumeration:

1. CurrentCulture
2. CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
3. InvariantCulture
4. InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
5. Ordinal
6. OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: I don't believe this is supported in L2S.

Comment: You can use `IndexOf`, but not the overload? Can you explain that?

Comment: If I were smarter or on the L2S team, I could.  I had to just try it to make sure the L2S provider balked at it, and it does. `NotSupportedException`.